# Before asking 'identify-this' questions

Tags: discussion, identify, question-quality

I'm brand new to the site, but the first thing I noticed is that there are many 'identify-this' questions with a picture. Nowadays, there are reverse image search engines such as [tineye](http://www.tineye.com/) which makes finding information from an image so much easier.

I took a random (honest) question of this type - [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10611/scary-movie-about-spiders), went to tineye and searched for the image - [results](http://www.tineye.com/search/1ca377c50f4b57d18d8574160562e18f7baa63e2/) - went to one of the links, and found [this](http://horror101withdrac.blogspot.ca/2013/05/spiders-2000-movie-review.html). Boom! Identified. It's not so hard.

How can we make sure questions like these only get asked after the OP has had a genuine attempt at it. And how should we promote the use of tools like tineye to the community?

Comment: I don't disagree with this in general. I'm not sure this is a big issue with the site to be honest, certainly most identification questions don't have pictures, and many that do are from quizzes and we close these immediately anyway. I do tend to use image search tools, such as TinEye or Google Image Search here.  I should point out that the question referred to here was asked before the link you found existed however.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best fixes I have seen for people who ask questions that could be answered with a simple Google Search is to locate their answer through a Google Search, then send them a link to their answer via [Let Me Google That For You](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how%20do%20I%20find%20an%20answer%20on%20google).

While there is no comparable Let Me Tin Eye That For You, the best thing you can do is to post an answer which is prefaced by a boilerplate sentence where you state outright that you used the Tin Eye website (with a link, preferably pre-loaded using the image they posted) to discover their answer, and then post their answer.

For example, using your question data:

> I submitted your image to [Tin Eye](http://www.tineye.com/search/1ca377c50f4b57d18d8574160562e18f7baa63e2/) and via deductive reasoning determined it was **movie name**.  {Additional info.}

That user and potential others who read your answer may then recognize Tin Eye as a tool for them to use as well, going forward.

Comment: I like this because I had a few ID questions based on screen shots and I wasn't aware that those kind of tools existed. So you're giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Except that this passive aggressive behavior is widely considered rude and arrogant and has even been **banned across the network.** Why didn't you know that? Next time, **[try searching meta before posting](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+LMGTFY)**, noob. <wink>

Comment: Stop "hot-dogging" it, Rob. :P